# Android - way to load large data in ListView any cache mechanism on cursors or something which loads listview faster

Tags: android

I have a large dataset in database, I want to load this data in listview as fast as possible.
I have tried a Async task which progressively adds elements from database to list which is bind to list view. But first records get loaded faster but to scroll down to last record it take much time.
Is there any way that android cache these lists cursors and is synchronized with database like observers?
There are examples like sms apps, contact list apps which loads faster.
How to get such fast speed in loading listview?